# promise within promise with for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I want to call multiple api, the second api need something from the first api, I created two promise but now I'm stuck, how can I execute what needs to be done and wait all of them finish?

```
createAccount(this.state.item) //promise
.then(resp=>{

  this.state.albums.forEach(o=>{ //array of object
    createAlbum(resp.id, { //promise
      ...o
    })
  })
})
```

I'm using `bluebird` I got a hint, using `promise.all` but I have no clue how that work with forEach, I can't control how many albums are there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What do you want the resolution value of the outermost promise to be? What about the documentation for `Promise.all` was unclear? What does your attempt to use `Promise.all` look like?

Comment: It is explained pretty nicely in the [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)

Comment: @OrB but I don't get it :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create the account, then create some number of albums stored in an array. This is indeed exactly what `Promise.all` would be for:

```
createAccount(this.state.item)
.then(resp =>
    Promise.all(
        this.state.albums.map(o => createAlbum(resp.id, o))
    )
);
```

You'll need to either return the promise created by `then` to the caller, or handle errors on it (e.g., via `.catch`), as is always the case with promises.

More about `Promise.all` in [the bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: why map not foreach? how can I get the resp of Promise.all?

Comment: @SharonChai: *"why map not foreach?"* Did you look up what `map` does vs. what `forEach` does? *"how can I get the resp of Promise.all?"* I suggest working through some tutorials on promises. The result of the call to `Promise.all` above is the resolution value of the promise returned by the `then` above.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want but if you want to process each album you can use `Promise.all` with `Array.prototype.map` Your code will look something like this:

```
//if this is part of a function you shoud
// return createAccount ...
createAccount(this.state.item) //promise
.then(
  resp=>//arrow function without {} will return first statement
        //resp=>Promise.all(... is same as resp=>{ return Promise.all(...
    Promise.all(
      this.state.albums.map(
        album=>{
          //not sure why you want to keep calling createAlbum
          //  but only have one id, did you want to do album.id?
          createAlbum(resp.id)
          .then(
            o=>{
              //do something with o, album or response, they are all available
              return album;//you acn for example return album
            }
          )
        }
      )  
    )
)
.then(
  results=>{
    //results is an array of whatever o=> returns
  }
).catch(
  error=>{
    console.warn("something went wrong:",error);
  }
);
```

Please let me know if you have any questions, will probably need:

1. The code you are using
2. Add some `console.log("album is:",JSON.stringify(album,undefined,2)` statements in the code (album is an example). So you can debug some of the code yourself and identify if the data objects you think you have are actually the object you have.
3. Any errors that you have. Press F12 in browser and look at console and network tab. The console will show errors and your console.logs and network will show your xhr with the errors/response.

Comment: use map so u can do then? why not foreach?

Comment: @SharonChai forEach doesn't return anything. It is more appropriate for side effects like: "for each email send Christmas card" instead of "for each url give me a promise that resolves in the content of that url" That is called mapping urls to promises of responses.

Answer (score 0):

Use promise.map instead of promise.all, find example below for reference-

```
Promise.map(this.state.albums, function(fileName) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    return x;
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
});
```